# Surface as an intersection of a sphere and a cone

Tags: surfaces, parametrization

I have to evaluate the density of the solid bounded by the surface
$$(x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2})^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}$$
How can I see this surface? Is it a intersection of a sphere and a cone?

Comment: [Wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(x**2%2By**2%2Bz**2)**2%3Dx**2%2By**2&t=crmtb01)  The picture makes it look like a torus, but it isn't really, because the origin is on the surface.

Comment: What is the domain of $x,y,z$? Is it reals?

Comment: @Somos it just asks the density of this surface (and it gives the density function).

Answer (score 0):

Let $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^@+z^2}$ and $a=\sqrt{x^2+y^@}$ then the curve is the curve $r^2=a$, which is the 2D curve $x^2+y^2-x=0$ on the subset $\{x\ge 0\}$ , rotated around the axis $z$.

Comment: and the curve in question is the circle centered at $(\frac{1}{2},0)$ of radius $\frac{1}{2}$,

Comment: a torus-like circle-revolution-surface.

Answer (score 0):

It is the surface of revolution where a circle of diameter $1$ is tangent to the revolution axis at the origin. It is a torus where the radius of revolution is equal to the radius of the circular cross section.